# Get image path from src="cid:image.png..." resource

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to parse e-mail, and the links in the img tags have an unusual format. I'm not strong in regular expressions. I would be glad to hear your suggestions how to get a normal link from this :

```
src="cid:image006.png@01D4225D.4CE86AB0"
```

Comment: Please include your desired output. And also some more examples.

Comment: What do you want to parse from the string? What should be the desired output. What you have tried till now please describe the problem.

Comment: If you are parsing html emails, then you probably want to use beautiful soup, rather than custom regex.

Comment: Please consider choosing the right answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the image link from that tag, because CID actually references the images in the email that you received. This image has been attached to your email.

Comment: I keep the letters in the directory. There, the application/octet-stream attachments and  image/* attachment are saved, and I need a simple relative path.

Comment: The only information that your `src=...` provides is the file name that you can get with a simple regex like  `(?<=\:)(.*\n?)(?=\@)`